# Where are database of contents inside the widget - wordpress stored?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, date, widget, backup

I transferred the contents of the site and the database but the contents of the widget were not moved.

I have a full backup from the previous site.

I want the exact location inside the backup ( wordpress ) or name it in datebase??

Comment: it will be under 'options' table

Comment: yes,its true,thx